# IPFS js cant connect to ws://127.0.0.1:8081/p2p/

Tags: vue.js, websocket, ipfs, js-ipfs

I am running a ipfs js instance which is working well but i get some error with web sockets and I am unsure why it is even calling a local IP ?

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:8081/p2p/QmSoLV4Bbm51jM9C4gDYZQ9Cy3U6aXMJDAbzgu2fzaDs64.

In firefox on deployed site no errors but in safari

The page at https://alpha.nodenogg.in/ was not allowed to run insecure content from ws://127.0.0.1:8081/p2p/Qmbut9Ywz9YEDrz8ySBSgWyJk41Uvm2QJPhwDJzJyGFsD6.

here is some of the code I am using, any pointers and to where this error is coming from would be great. The site however does what I want with IPFS so I am not sure what this error is related to. Thank you

```
import VueIpfs from 'ipfs'
const ipfs = VueIpfs.create()
```

```
mounted: function () {
    // console.log(VueIpfs)
    this.getIpfsNodeInfo()
  },
```

```
  methods: {
async getIpfsNodeInfo() {
  try {
    // Await for ipfs node instance.
    node = await ipfs

  } catch (err) {
    // Set error status text.
    this.status = `Error: ${err}`
  }
},

onFileSelected(event) {
  this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
  this.saveIPFS()
},

async saveIPFS() {
  try {
    this.fileContents = await node.add(this.selectedFile)
    this.getIPFS()
  } catch (err) {
    // Set error status text.
    this.status = `Error: ${err}`
  }
},

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not indeed an issue with your code.

I believe you are using `webrtc-star` for transport and discovery (it is the default for browser environment in `js-ipfs`, if you did not custom it, you should have it).

So, you use `webrtc-star` to discover other peers to talk to. Once you get to know these peers, your node will get to know all the multiaddrs that peer is announcing to the network. There will be nodes announcing several addresses, some of which are local IP addresses. `js-libp2p` has a feature to specify `announce` and `noAnnounce` addresses in its configuration, which allows people to be able to specify in these cases if you should not announce your local addr and announce the public one. However, this feature is not widely known at the moment.

However, from a libp2p/IPFS stand point, we need to find a better way of catching and logging these errors since they seem error related to your node/code, but they are a result of bad propagation of multiaddrs that other peers announce in the network.

I hope that I answered your question, and we will look into a patch to get rid of these errors

Comment: Thanks. No problem, just clutters up the console so hard to spot my own errors 

Comment: I am now finding page will not load on mobile safari as it reports "a problem repeatedly occurred safari" I am still trying to debug annoyingly and I wonder if this is causing concern